# Display numbered list in TextArea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multiple select and a textarea. All the selected values from multiple select are displayed in the textarea. I am using below code to do this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#select").change(function () {
      var sel = $("#select").val();
         $("#selected").html(sel.join('\n'));
    });
});
```

select is id of multiple select and selected is the textarea id. I want to display serial numbers also, i.e., displaying selected values in textarea in numbered list. How can I do this?

Comment: Huh, you want to do what now? Maybe you should try and explain this ***a lot*** better ?

Comment: You lost me at _"I want to display serial numbers also, i.e., displaying selected values in textarea in numbered format."_

Comment: I get it. He wants to display it like a numbered list.

Comment: put an example on jsfiddle.net, would be much easier to understand you then.

Comment: @Barmar you got me right

Comment: You should clarify what you are trying to achieve by showing the input data and at least a mock-up of the desired output.  But if I understand you correctly, it would be better not to use a textarea and instead use `<ol><li></li></ol>` where each `<li>` contains the selected values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put an ordered list in `#selected`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#select").change(function () {
        var ol = $("<ol>").appendTo($("#selected").empty());
        $("#select option:selected").each(function () {
            ol.append($("<li>", {
                text: $(this).val()
            }));
        });
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/j4sQd/3/)

For a textarea you can't put HTML so you have to format it yourself:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#select").change(function () {
        var vals = [];
        $("#select option:selected").each(function (i) {
            vals.push((i+1) + '. ' + $(this).val());
        });
        $("#selected").text(vals.join("\n"));
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/j4sQd/11/)

Comment: I am unable to get list. I am beginner to JQUERY. Can u please be more clear on where to include above code in my code

Comment: Updated the answer with the full code and a jsfiddle

Comment: Its working with div tag, but its not working with a textarea. What could be the problem?

Comment: HTML isn't interpreted in a textarea, it's just plain text.

Comment: So is there any way I can include this numbered list in textarea?